# Querying a hierarchy of parent->children - I want to sum an amount, but make sure I only count rows which have the same parent once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an n-level hierarchy of categories, and a set of products which can be arbitrarily mapped into categories. The same product can be in multiple categories, including multiple children of the same parent.

What I'm trying to do is write a report that shows the total ordered amount of a product in a parent category. For instance, if the parent category is "Bikes" and the children are "Bikes - Boys" and "Bikes - Girls", I want to make sure I'm including an ordered product only once in the "Bikes" category row even if it is in both child categories.

The query I have now is:

```
WITH
  hierarchy AS (
    SELECT
      prod.id as [prodId]
    , prod.Name as [prodName]
    , cat.id as [catId]
    , cat.parentId as [catParentId]
    , cat.name as [catName]
    FROM product_cat_map AS link
    INNER JOIN product AS prod
      ON prod.id = link.productId
    INNER JOIN category AS cat
      ON cat.id = link.catId
    where cat.parentid is not null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      child.prodId as [prodId]
    , child.prodName as [prodName]
    , parent.id as [catId]
    , parent.parentId as [catParentId]
    , parent.name as [catName]
    FROM hierarchy AS child
    INNER JOIN category AS parent
      ON parent.id = child.catParentId
    where parent.parentid is not null
  )
select h.catName as [category],h.prodId as [product],sum(o.amount)
from hierarchy h
inner join ord o on h.prodId = o.productId
group by h.catName, h.prodId
```

The hierarchy "with" clause works great. In my example, if the bike that is in both "Bikes - Boys" and "Bikes - Girls" is ordered once, I get three rows - "Bikes", "Bikes - Boys", and "Bikes - Girls".

Using my example above, though, if the bike that is in both "Bikes - Boys" and "Bikes - Girls" costs $1 and is ordered twice, the first row of my result set is category="Bikes", product=1, total=$4.

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious, but I can't wrap my head around it. Help?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `WITH RECURSIVE`?

Comment: Sorry- should've mentioned that this is running on SQL Server. I think WITH RECURSIVE is postgres syntax. It runs as a recursive query as written in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try changing this line:

```
from hierarchy h
```

to:

```
from (select distinct * from hierarchy) h
```